# Ubuntu 18.04 - Can't Mount Devices by Double Click on File Manager If They Are Defined in `fstab`

Tags: 18.04, mount, filesystem, ntfs, fstab

I have few HD with NTFS on my computer.
Usually I can see those Hard Drives as devices in the File Manager home (`computer:///`).

By double clicking them they are mounted.

I wanted to make sure when they are mounted to be mounted as Read Only.
So following some answers here I edited `fstab`.

Let's take a single example for a line I added in `fstab`:

```
UUID=5A8469DC8469BAE1    /mnt/D/  ntfs  defaults,noauto,user,ro   0    0
```

I defined my Windows `D:` drive to be mounted into `/mnt/D`.
I created the folder `/mnt/D/`.

The problem is when I now click on the HD on File Manager I get `Unable to mount location - can't mount file`.

Yet if I mount is manually it is mounted and I can see the files in the corresponding folder.
I saw it is a known problem in Ubuntu - https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/error-unable-to-mount-location/7508/6 (Also related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564047). Is that so?

The output of `mount`:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/D type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,user)
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to fix this? I don't want auto mounting but I want that by double click things will be mounted according to the settings in `fstab`. Namely NTFS to be mounted as *Read Only*.
2. Is there a better way to achieve this? Namely whenever I double click on a device in the File Manager which is a NTFS partition it will be mounted as Read Only.

Answer (score 0):

Once you edit the /etc/fstab file (sudo vim etc/fstab or sudo nano /etc/fstab; you should specify the **file system type** **(ext4, NFTS, ext3, etc.)**

## Please see the following example:

UUID=5A8469DC8469BAE1 /mnt/D/ **ext4** defaults 0 2

Where:

file system: UUID=5A8469DC8469BAE1

mount point: /mnt/D/

**type: ext 4**

options: defaults

dump: 0

pass: 2

## Save the fstab file based on your text editor

## In the Terminal type:

mount -a

## Create directory in the root directory is as follows:

mkdir /mnt/D

## Type reboot

## Check mount point

Comment: Thank you for the effort. But this doesn't answer my question. This is a general way to auto mount a volume. Which is not what I'm after.